# Laravel - Eloquent. Autoreference another row inside the same table/model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `Group.php` model. The db table is like the columns: `id`, `title`, `description`, `parent`.

The `parent` column has reference to a id of another group inside this table. So if a record has value in parent column then it is a child of another group. How can I go with eloquent and get the hierarchy of the the nested groups.

I want to use this so when I am in blade I want to do `foreach` for the outer parent groups and then do `foreach` for each child to see if has any other child and then do `foreach` again.

Answer (score 0):

you should create children relationship in Group Model:

```
 function children(){
    return $this->hasMany(Group::class, 'id','parent');
 }
```

in controller you need to create recursion function

```
function list_groups($groups)
{
  $data = [];

  foreach($groups as $group)
  {
    $data[] = [
      'id' = $group->id,
      'title' => $group->title,
        //ToDo addd Your Data Here
      'children' = list_groups($group->children),
    ];
  }

  return $data;
}
```

now you can use

```
 $root_groups = Group::with('children')->whereParent(0)->get(); //get All Root group
 $groups = list_groups($root_groups); // now get all childs
```

**Note**, Code Not Tested

Comment: It is strange. The eager loading is totally ignored. When I try `Group::with('children')->toSql()` it returns `select * from groups`.